# Eclipse Milo Server (OPC-UA) access through https web browser

Tags: eclipse, web, server, opc-ua, milo

How I can access Eclipse Milo Server (OPC-UA) access through https web browser

I setup server from https://github.com/eclipse/milo/tree/master/milo-examples
I have setup server but when I try to access it from browser below error is coming on server logs

url =  https://127.0.0.1:8443/milo

```
> Blockquote

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1647) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1615) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1781) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1070) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:896) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:766) ~[?:1.8.0_212] 
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:281) ~[netty-handler-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1324) ~[netty-handler-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1219) ~[netty-handler-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1266) ~[netty-handler-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:498) ~[netty-codec-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:437) ~[netty-codec-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s not meant to be accessed via a web browser. Any HTTP/HTTPS support it has is only as a transport layer, not for access in a browser.